# jquery ui resizable left-bottom handle to resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using jquery-ui-resizable plugin in my project.

By default when you make a DOM Object jquery-ui-resizable the resizable handle will appear on right-bottom corner, I need the re-sizable handle on left-bottom corner.

**--- EDIT ---**

One more thing, it should not be re-sizable using right border but should be re-sizable using left border.

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should use the `handles`

```
supported: { n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw }.
```

This will create the Handles on the side you specified. Default values are

```
'e, s, se'
```

Code examples

Initialize a resizable with the handles option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable({ handles: 'n, e, s, w' });
```

Get or set the handles option, after init.

```
//getter
var handles = $( ".selector" ).resizable( "option", "handles" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).resizable( "option", "handles", 'n, e, s, w' );
```

Comment: +1, Thanks @Ahmed for your reply, i think it will work. Please let me try.

Comment: Just a heads-up for future visitors: This answer is correct in terms of adding a FUNCTIONAL handle, but it will not create a VISIBLE handle like the one in the OP’s screenshot. See Dr.Molle's answer below for more details.

Answer (score 10):

Additional to Ahmed's answer:
jQueryUI doesn't include a icon for the sw-handle and also doesn't apply a icon-class for the sw-handle. You may use some CSS to add an icon:

```
#resizable .ui-resizable-sw{background:url(path/to/custom_icon.gif) no-repeat;}
```

Answer (score 7):

To do re-sizing from all sides following code can also be used

```
     var resizeOpts = { 
      handles: "all" ,autoHide:true
    }; 
$( ".selector" ).resizable(resizeOpts);
```

and autoHide equal true means that grip icon will automatically hide when mouse pointer is taken away from dom object.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for this SW solution. What i had to do to make it work is add the ui-icon classes to the created div just after the call to resizable().

```
$( "#wproof" ).resizable({handles: "w, sw, s"});
$('.ui-resizable-sw').addClass('ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-sw');
```

Then define the icon by taking it in images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
It is a small 9X9 area at the bottom. Make a .png file of it ( with a rotation ! ) and add the style to the given class :

```
<style>
.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-sw { 
    background-image: url(your 9x9 icon.png); }
.ui-resizable-sw {
    bottom: 1px;
    left: 1px;
}
</style>
```

The bottom and left are set at -5px in jquery-ui css

Comment: Good find! In my version of jQuery UI, the image had a slightly different filename, but it was right there in the "images" folder. (It's too bad the [jQuery UI icon set](https://api.jqueryui.com/resources/icons-list.html) doesn't include a "grip" icon for all four corners. That would save us some trouble!)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the standard cursor property is what is used by the UI CSS

```
.ui-resizable-sw {
cursor: sw-resize;
height: 7px;
width: 100%;
top: -5px;
left: 0;
}
```

Also it seems that cursor does not display and resizable is not enabled for the side of the element that is used for positioning  - for example:  a div positioned using left:20px top:20px will not enable resizing on those left and top sides

I discovered this after adding all handles but then they all never showed up !
Update: Apparently there is some problem within my app that is causing my problem. Testing on JSFiddle all handles do work as expected using the same version of JQuery.....argggggg