# resize the element from any side

Tags: jquery, css

i have done the resize of elements by using resizable . but there is problem that user can only resize from right end bottom end. i want add the feature of resize from any end.
 i use the file below

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

i want to know that can i add some feature or manually do in the code inside.

Comment: JqueryUI provides resize from bottom right end only. You can make it draggable also. So, It will allow to take top corner wherever required and resize from bottom right corner only.

Comment: Use the **handles** as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871558/jquery-ui-resizable-left-bottom-handle-to-resize
And here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#option-handles

Comment: ok Umesh i  think user can drag the element from center also . so i want to know is there any feature to add the other two corner for resize.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add the feature of resize from top or left end, add the option 'handles' in the call function, like this :

```
$( "#resizable" ).resizable({handles: 'n,w'});
```

options available are n,e,s,w,se,sw,ne,nw , and you can also use 'all'