# How can we make jquery terminal screen adjustable?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, node.js, terminal, jquery-terminal

I am using jquery terminal to run commands in my project, in that I want to make its screen adjustable, I am unable to do that, can anybody help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read this carefully before asking https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: what you mean by adjustable?

Comment: adjustable means that I want to change its width from my mouse pointer, just like we do in any popup, to make it large or smaller in width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [jQuery Terminal inside jQuery UI dialog](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/examples.php#dterm) or maybe use resizable from jQuery UI

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="term"></div>
</div>

$('.wrapper').resizable();
$('.term').terminal();

.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
.term {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/WZvYGj)**

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this and will let you know the result.

Comment: I also used handles, because I wanted it from left side. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871558/jquery-ui-resizable-left-bottom-handle-to-resize

Comment: @NitishaTambi if the answer solve your question you can mark it as the right answer by clicking check mark icon.